# Where is the Nautilus/file sorting algorithm defined?

Tags: nautilus, file-sorting

When I look at files as listed in Nautilus (sort by name), if there are both English and non-ASCII (in my case Japanese) characters, some characters (kana) are mixed with the ASCII characters out of order. (Windows segregates them properly.)

I have checked many related questions here, and it seems like the sort order is hard-coded in Nautilus, and so can't be changed.

But my question here is not how to change it, but where the sort algorithm is actually defined, relating to non-ASCII characters.
I'm using 18.04 if that matters. My locale is US-English.

Terminal `ls` command seems to give the same order, so this may be a system setting rather than specific to Nautilus, but again I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: You can share some information about the current locale.

Comment: Thanks, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

**Prerequisites**: First check that the locale of your language (in your case, the Japanese locale) is installed in your system, using the command:

```
$ grep -v '^#' /etc/locale.gen
```

If the Japanese locale (`ja_JP.UTF8`) is not listed, you have to add it to your system using:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

---

Generally, sorting order is a system setting and is related to your current locale. You mentioned that you are using the "US-English" locale. I assume it is `en_US.UTF-8` and probably this is the reason you see file names sorted in US sort order.

First, test from command line the following. Go to the directory containing your English and Japanese named files and enter the command:

```
$ LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF8 ls
```

If this command displays the files in the order you want, then you may try Nautilus also with this command:

```
$ LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF8 nautilus .
```

If you get an error message like:

> ... Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale.

check once more:

```
$ grep -v '^#' /etc/locale.gen
```

to see which locales are enabled in your system. If the Japanese locale is not enabled, you have to add it to your system using:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Note: In the above commands (`ls` and `nautilus`) I have prefixed with an environment variable ***that with affect only that command invocation***. If you want to change your locale ***permanently***, you will have to change the "default locale" also with the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` command.

Comment: I only have 16.04 system at the moment to test this, but after the first command all non-ASCII came up as ????.

Comment: Is the Japanese locale installed as I explain at the end of my answer?

Comment: I didn't go to that because that read as in case of some error message. I guess `$ grep -v '^#' /etc/locale.gen` should be checked in any case. As you suspected, only en_us.UTF-8 is installed.

Comment: As in my original question, is this character order documented anywhere? Because it seems that Unicode should get the order correct anyway.

Comment: AFAIK, Unicode has nothing to do with the sort order of each and every language on the world. For further information, you can google "locale sort order". But, the `man` page of the `sort` command, for example mentions this: `*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order. Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.`

Answer (score 0):

The Nautilus/File sorting algorithm seems to be defined in [GLib](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/):

> GLib is the low-level core library that forms the basis for projects
> such as GTK and GNOME.
>
> The official download locations are:
> https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib

And more specifically in [gunicollate.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/blob/master/glib/gunicollate.c) and it's `g_utf8_collate_key_for_filename()` function.

It is discussed in various issues like

"[g_utf8_collate_key_for_filename() corner cases with digits](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/1344)"

or this old bug on Launchpad:

"[Sorting by name doesn't work well with digits or special chars](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/322271)"

where [comment #10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/322271/comments/10) suggest using this hack to solve the sorting problem :

https://github.com/heralight/GlibSortFileNameHackLibrary